# in a kotlin can't get text from Textview in for loop

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing kotlin code to dynamically add TextView widget.
But I can't get the text in the for loop with compile error("Unresolved reference: text")
how can I solve this problem?

MainActivity.kt

```
    private val vBinding by lazy {ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)}

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(vBinding.root)

     // add TextView to linearLayout
     vBinding.addTopic.setOnClickListener {
            val newTV = TextView(this)
            newTV.text = "test"
            vBinding.linearLayout.addView(newTV)
        }

     // get a text from textView but don't work
     vBinding.submitBtn.setOnClickListener {
            for(item in vBinding.linearLayout.children){
                Log.d("test", "${item.text}")
              }
     }
```

layoutFile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
...
    tools:context=".InputActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:text="SAVE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/addTopic"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (item in vBinding.linearLayout.children){
   Log.d("test", "${(item as TextView).text}")
}
```

You should cast your children views to TextView. What if there are only image views? Or a recycler? Or something else which doesn't have a "text" property?

You can take a look at this [article](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators), it's about type checks/casts in Kotlin.

Comment: chaining `filterIsInstance` (`linearLayout.children.filterIsInstance<TextView>()`) will give you a `List<TextView>`, which is nice because the cast is done and you only get the views of that type. It's good for e.g. setting a click listener on a lot of `Button`s without having to specify all their IDs!

Comment: @cactustictacs more than agree here!